# how i could properly set a submit from an Ext.form.panel, to manage a xml respone?

Tags: xml, forms, extjs

My Ext.form.Panel should "eat" an xml response from server, but extjs raise

```
uncaught exception: You're trying to decode an invalid JSON String: 
< ?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>< root>< user >admin< /user>< roles>Administrator< /roles">"< roles>Operator< /roles>< /root>"
```

This is the handler on the submit button:

```js
var form = this.up('form').getForm();
if (form.isValid()) {
    form.submit({
        success: function(form, request) {
            console.log("OK")
            //Ext.Msg.alert('Success', action.result.msg);
        },
        failure: function(form, request) {
            console.log("KO")
            //Ext.Msg.alert('Failed', action.result.msg);
        }
    });
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks for any advice.

Answer (score 1):

You can receive xml for your form.

You just need to configure your form with an XML reader like this:

```
    reader : Ext.create('Ext.data.reader.Xml', {
        model: 'example.contact',
        record : 'contact',
        successProperty: '@success'
    }),
```

There's a full example here:
http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/ext-4.0.0/examples/form/xml-form.html

Comment: the Ext.form.Panel reader is used to read data when executing 'load' actions not for the 'submit' action..

Comment: You can configure an XML reader to consume whatever you want coming back from the server. Configure a second XML reader to consume your response if you wish.It's not just for load actions.

Answer (score 0):

The form requires an answer in JSON format and can not process XML data. You need to change the server response to JSON or use an Ajax request with your form fields as parameters.

Comment: thanks, 
i hoped i could set an option somewhere, since the Ext.form.Panel use an Ajax request.
I'll use an Ajax request

Comment: Like mwrf pointed out in detail you can set the reader to be `Ext.data.reader.Xml` to recieve XML data.